# Is it possible to check if '+' can be applied for a Type at compile time?

Tags: c#, generics, operators, extension-methods

I want to write a generic `CumulativeSum` method. Here is the code

```
public static IEnumerable<T> CumulativeSum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : struct
{
    T sum = default(T);
    foreach (T i in source)
    {
        sum += i; // Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'
        yield return sum;
    }
}
```

As shown in the comment (and as expected), compiler cannot know if a `T` can be added to a `T`, hence giving error.

One solution is writing an extension method for each and every type I need.

Another solution is replacing `T sum = default(T);` with `dynamic sum = default(T);`. But this may cause runtime errors (still best way for me).

Is there a keyword for operator overloads which I can use in the conditions like using `where T : struct` ?

Comment: There is no constraint for this. What would you like to happen if `+` operator is not applicable for the type.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel If it is not applicable I'd like to write a method for that struct. I'd like to know at compile time if possible, but I think it is not.

Comment: @Rawling If your guess is right, then answer is not possible :)

Comment: [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) is promising. Give a try..